# How to get wkwebView content size in swift

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

How to get wkwebView's scrollView content size in swift. My wkwebView inside collectionViewCell and when i try get content height like this, it returns cell content size

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        let webHeight = webView.scrollView.frame.height
        htmlContentHeight = webHeight
        print(webHeight)
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try  webView.scrollView.contentSize, but I've found that it not always returns correct values, just for simplest pages. So I've use script like this:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.height") { (result, error) in
    if error == nil {
        print(result)
    }
}

webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.width") { (result, error) in
    if error == nil {
        print(result)
    }
}
```

Comment: @Igor, what about device rotation?

Comment: it depend from page proof, in most cases you should recalculate sizes after rotation